# Converting imperative style user input menu to functional programming style

Tags: functional-programming, scala, console

I am currently trying to teach myself scala by rewriting projects from my intro CS class, which was taught in C++. In addition to just learning the syntax I am trying to gain understanding of how functional programming works and what is considered good functional programming style.

Below I've included both the original code, which is a simple while loop that continues looping until the user selects the 'quit' option, and my attempt at a functional equivalent. Have I done this correctly? What could be improved?

Original imperative version in C++:

> ```
> int main()
> {
>   int option = -1;
>
>   while (option != 3)
>   {        
>     cout << fixed;
>     cout << "Please select one of the following:" << "\n1 - one" <<
>       "\n2 - two" << "\n3 - quit" << endl;
>     cin >> option;
>     if (option == 1)
>     {
>       cout << "selected 1" << endl;
>     }
>     else if (option == 2)
>     {
>       cout << "selected 2" << endl;
>     }
>     else if (option == 3)
>     {
>       cout << "selected quit.\n";
>     }
>     else
>     {
>       cout << "Sorry, that command is not recognized. ";
>     }
>   }
>   return 0;  
> }
> ```

My attempt at a functional version in scala:

```
def menu(option: Int) {
  println("""|Please select one of the following:
             |  1 - one 
             |  2 - two
             |  3 - quit""".stripMargin)
  if (option == 1) {
    println("selected 1")
    val opt = StdIn.readInt
    menu(opt)
  }
  else if (option == 2) {
    println("selected 2")
    val opt = StdIn.readInt
    menu(opt)
  }
  else if (option == 3) {
    println("selected quit")
  }
  else {
    println("Sorry, that command is not recognized")
  }
}

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  println("""|Please select one of the following:
             |  1 - one 
             |  2 - two
             |  3 - quit""".stripMargin)
  val opt = StdIn.readInt
  menu(opt)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the Scala features you need to get used to using is `match` - it is your friend. One of your very *best* friends.

Also, the way you have defined `menu` is recursive, with no bounding. In this particular case, it's probably not an issue, but it is, in general a *Really Bad Idea*.

Finally, you have repeated the printing of the menu and reading of the option. In general, one should follow [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

So how about something like the code below. Note, one of the rare cases tailor made for `do...while`.

```
def menu(option: Int): Boolean = {
  option match {
    case 1 =>
      println("selected 1")
      true
    case 2 =>
      println("selected 2")
      true
    case 3 =>
      println("selected quit")
      false
    case _ => // the else case
      println("Sorry, that command is not recognized")
      true
  }
}

def readOption: Int = {
  println("""|Please select one of the following:
             |  1 - one 
             |  2 - two
             |  3 - quit""".stripMargin)
  StdIn.readInt()
}

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  var opt = 0
  do {
    opt = readOption
  } while (menu(opt))
}
```

Alternately, if you wanted to something more functional, you could change `menu` to something like this:

```
val actionMap = Map[Int, () => Boolean](1 -> handleOne, 2 -> handleTwo, 3 ->handleThree)

def handleOne(): Boolean = {
  println("selected 1")
  true
}

def handleTwo(): Boolean = {
  println("selected 2")
  true
}

def handleThree(): Boolean = {
  println("selected quit")
  false
}

def menu(option: Int): Boolean = {
  actionMap.get(option) match {
    case Some(f) => f()
    case None =>
      println("Sorry, that command is not recognized")
      false
  }
}
```

Where `actionMap` maps each `Int` to a function that takes no parameters and returns a `Boolean`. In menu, we use `option` as the key into the map and then call the result (if there is one).

Comment: Great, that looks fantastic! Thanks so much for the quick response.

Comment: Very clean & reusable too.

Answer (score 2):

A similar approach to the accepted answer, yet emphasizing encapsulation, as follows,

```
object OptMenu extends App {

  sealed abstract class Menu {
    def menu()
  }

  case object OptOne extends Menu {
    def menu() = println("selected 1") // do other stuff as well
    override def toString = "1 - one"
  }

  case object OptTwo extends Menu {
    def menu() = println("selected 2") // do other stuff as well
    override def toString = "2 - two"
  }

  case object OptQuit extends Menu {
    def menu() = println("selected quit")
    override def toString = "3 - quit"
  }

  def help() = "Please select one of the following:\n" + 
                Seq(OptOne, OptTwo, OptQuit).mkString("\n")

  println(help())

  io.StdIn.readInt match {
    case 1 => OptOne.menu()
    case 2 => OptTwo.menu()
    case 3 => OptQuit.menu()
    case _ => sys.error("Unrecognized option.")
  }
}
```

Each menu action in wrapped in a dedicated case object, each menu can be specialised. Encapsulation here facilitates scalability as well as specializing desired menus. Every case object that extends `Menu` must implement a function `menu()` with specialized logic. In this illustration, the abstract `menu()` (and all the specializations) deliver a `Unit` value.

Idiomatic in Scala is to override the `toString` method, here used for showing help text by putting the case objects into a collection and then making a string out of it (`mkString`).

Pattern-matching as already suggested, follows. The call to `StdInt` has been prefixed with `io`; standard is also to `import scala.io.StdInt` especially for calling StdIn functions several times.

Note this code has no `main` function, instead `OptMenu` object overrides `App`. Thus for invoking this code from REPL consider

```
OptMenu.main(Array.empty)
```

For unrecognized options, `sys.error` will print a given error message and terminate the execution.

The match block could be refactored into this (similarly as in Donald's answer),

```
val opts = Map ( 1 -> OptOne, 2 -> OptTwo, 3 -> OptQuit)
opts.getOrElse( io.StdIn.readInt, sys.error("Unrecognised option") ).menu()
```

yet suggested here is the use of `getOrElse` together with sys.error. In contrast with the initial answer here, we type `menu()` once only, not three times, one for each possible match. This illustrates how encapsulation aids in scalability: we can add new options and `menu()` will be invoked anyway, recall this function is implemented by each case object that extends `Menu`.

Neater than throwing an exception, in order to discard console input that are not `Int`, consider this code,

```
util.Try(io.StdIn.readInt).toOption.getOrElse(sys.error("no int input"))
```

Here we invoke `readInt` to deliver an integer value, yet we convert it first into an `Option`, and in case we cannot extract its integer value, a sys.error termination is enforced.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Donald.McLean method but using one handle function being called with partial partially.

```
package scalaproj
import scala.io.StdIn


object MenuProg {

def handleInput(continue: Boolean)(op:Int): Boolean = {
  println("selected " + op)
  if (!continue) println("Quiting ...")
  continue  
}

val handleLoop = handleInput(true) _
val handleQuit = handleInput(false) _

val actionMap = Map[Int, (Int) => Boolean](1 -> handleLoop , 2 -> handleLoop, 3 ->handleQuit)


def menu(option: Int): Boolean = {
  actionMap.get(option) match {
    case Some(f) => f(option)
    case None =>
      println("Sorry, that command is not recognized")
      false
  }
}

def readOption: Int = {
  println("""|Please select one of the following:
             |  1 - one 
             |  2 - two
             |  3 - quit""".stripMargin)
  StdIn.readInt()
}

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  var opt = 0
  do {
    opt = readOption
  } while (menu(opt))
}

}
```

Comment: I find this is not a review but an alternative implementation of one of the answers without much explanation so I downvoted it.